Color error in ParametricPlot3D of several curves
Why are in the following context all 5 drawn curves blue and not the middle one red?

To replicate the above:
cols = Table[If[bb == 0, Red, Blue], {bb, -1, 1, 5/10}];
phi = {-1 + t^2, t (-1 + t^2), t a};
crvs = Table[phi /. {a -> aa}, {aa, -1, 1, 5/10}];
{Length[crvs], Length[cols]}
ParametricPlot3D[crvs, {t, -1.3, 1.3},
  PlotStyle -> cols]


{5, 5}


BTW,please post  phi. crvs//Evaluate do such colorize.

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@crvs, {t, -1.3, 1.3}, PlotStyle -> cols]

@Syed Wow - that worked! But why?

I tried @bbgodfrey 's version and it didn't work on v12.2 (that I use), so I added another Evaluate (recalling that ContourPlot has such behaviors that vary with versions). The variable crvs is already evaluated, so the Plot command shouldn't need another Evaluate. I am saying that I don't know the exact technical reason. Maybe someone else can write an answer to explain it.

@Syed The extra Evaluate certainly is not needed for Version 14.0, nor should it be.  Perhaps, there was a bug in Version 12.2.  I should add that my earlier comment was irrelevant, so I deleted it.

FWIW, I'm pretty sure there's a lot of complexity hidden away in how various syntactical structures are treated with functions that HoldFirst or HoldAll, and I'd be interested in better understanding it myself.
